# Error when trying to use adb shell in recovery mode

Tags: adb, shell, recovery-mode

I have a Chinese phone which I've been unable to install ClockworkMod on. I decided to try booting into recovery mode to manually backup/restore the system partition.

However, if I plug my phone into my PC while it's in recovery mode and issue the command

```
adb shell
```

it says:

```
exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I can only do very limited tasks, like `adb ls /` to see the filesystem, but nothing else.

How can I get adb shell working in recovery mode?

Answer (score -2):

In `mounts and storage`, `mount /system`.

Comment: This answer needs more detail to be useful.